# Reading strings from data file c++

Tags: c++, string, file

I am trying to read multiple strings from one data file into a struct. It kinda works, but there are some symbols,letters or numbers missing when I am trying to check if it fully works.

There's my function :

```
int n = 0;

ofstream out("showtext.txt");
ifstream in("test.txt");

while (!in.eof())
{   
    getline(in, A[n].Barkodas, ',');
    getline(in, A[n].Firma, ',');
    getline(in, A[n].Modelis, ',');
    getline(in, A[n].Data, ',');
    getline(in, A[n].Kiekis, ',');
    getline(in, A[n].Kaina, ',');
    getline(in, A[n].Sandelys);
    in.ignore(); // pereina i kita eilute
    out << A[n].Barkodas << " " << A[n].Firma << " " << A[n].Modelis << " " << A[n].Data << " " << A[n].Kiekis << " " << A[n].Kaina << " " << A[n].Sandelys << endl;
    n++;
}
in.close(); out.close();
```

What I get in the final is that the first numbers of 1-8 lines in my data file's strings are missing.
What's the problem ?

Comment: getline does not read numbers -- so im sure that is not what you mean.    Could you show what the fist lines of the file looks like?

Comment: Please include the definition of the type of A, and an example of your input file, and the output you get.

Comment: We can't solve your problem unless you share the text file with us.

Comment: @soren getline most certainly does read numbers..

Comment: @Afflicted -- getline reads characters from the stream -- they are never validated or converted to numbers such as int or float

Comment: Understood and agreed, getline is for reading strings but the numbers are still read in as part of the string, converting the after and or during is simple. Also Op could you please provide us with your full code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "first numbers missing", but if you mean that one character/digit is missing, the reason may be the `in.ignore`. The `getline` before that reads till the end of the line, so the ignore removes one character from the next line